# C++ Using two variables of same name in Derived and Base classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I've posted about this problem before ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539155/c-polymorphic-inherited-attribute-class-variables-across-base-and-derived-clas?noredirect=1#comment25509712_17539155)), this is a different approach to a solution. This solution to be seems to better encapsulate the behavior for those implementing the class, since it prevents them from needing to explicitly up cast.

Here's the problem:

I have a project in which I want to isolate core behavior in most objects, while providing additional behavior through derived objects. Simple enough:

```
class BaseA
{
    virtual void something() {}
}


class DerivedA : public BaseA
{
    void something() {}
    void somethingElse() {}
}
```

Now let’s say I also have a second set of classes, same inheritance scheme except that they aggregate the above classes. However, I would like the base version to use the base class, and the derived version in the derived class. My solution i was thinking about 'hiding' the base class variable by using the same name;

```
class BaseB
{
    BaseA *var;

    BaseB()
    {
        var = new BaseA();
    }

    virtual void anotherThing1();
    virtual void anotherThing2();
    virtual void anotherThing3();
}

class DerivedB : public BaseB
{
    DerivedA *var;

    DerivedB()
    {
        var = new DerivedA();
    }

    void anotherThing1();
    void anotherThing2();
    void anotherThing3();
    void andAnother1();
    void andAnother2();
}
```

The goal for this approach is so that functions that rely on the derived aggregated class no longer need to explicitly cast to achieve the gained functionality.

```
void func1( BaseB &b )
{
    b.anotherThing1();
    b.var->something();
}

void func2( DerivedB &b )
{
    b.anotherThing1();
    b.andAnother1();
    b.var->something();
    b.var->somethingElse();
}

void main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    BaseB    baseB;
    DerivedB derivedB;

    func1( baseB );
    func1( derivedB );
    func2( derivedB );
}
```

Would this be considered bad practice?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Wouldn't a `Base* var` do for both of them? If not, why do you want them to be the same name - is this intentionally trying to prevent others from being able to read the code or something?

Comment: I'm simply trying to get input on this approach. I initially thought of using just one Base *var (the link at the start of my post). But was wondering if this would be easier for those implementing the classes since they would never need to explicitly cast for derived functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this be considered bad practice?

Yes, it would be bad practice, because the `var` in the `Base` would be unused. It does not look like `DerivedB` should be deriving from `BaseB`: instead, they should be derived from the same abstract base class, like this:

```
class AbstractB {
public:
    virtual void anotherThing1() = 0;
    virtual void anotherThing2() = 0;
    virtual void anotherThing3() = 0;
};
class DerivedB1 : public AbstractB { // Former BaseB
    BaseA *var;

public:
    DerivedB1() {
        var = new BaseA();
    }
    virtual void anotherThing1();
    virtual void anotherThing2();
    virtual void anotherThing3();
};
class DerivedB2 : public AbstractB { // Former DerivedB
    DerivedA *var;
public:
    DerivedB2() {
        var = new DerivedA();
    }
    void anotherThing1();
    void anotherThing2();
    void anotherThing3();
    void andAnother1();
    void andAnother2();
};
```

General principle in use here is that you should try making all your non-leaf classes in your inheritance hierarchy abstract.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping not to use this sort of a pattern, since almost every overridden function in a derived class simply calls the base version, then runs a few extra lines. So by completely separating the classes, there will be a lot of code duplication.

Comment: @Pondwater You can move the shared functionality into an abstract class, with derived classes providing specific adjustments to the logic. See [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern (has nothing to do with C++ templates).

Comment: The shared functionality is dependent upon the aggregated object. So in my case anotherThing#() requires the var attribute. DerivedB2 would require var to be DerivedA.

Comment: @Pondwater You can ry applying the same refactoring to the `BaseA`/`DerivedA` pair: use virtual functions to make `DerivedB1` and `DerivedB2` work in terms of the base functionality of only `BaseA` (i.e. the call would be the same, but the actual function would be based on the runtime type due to polymorphism). This should unify parts of `DerivedB1`/`DerivedB2` code. Put the non-unifiable code into `DerivedB1`/`DerivedB2` virtuals, and call them from the abstract base to complete the template method implementation.